# jquery multiple click()'s giving unexpected results on tooltip(NOT Jquery UI)

Tags: jquery

I have included a fiddle at [http://jsfiddle.net/RunLC/1/], with some necessary adaptations.

I am building my own tooltip and manage to have it ALMOST work.

Actually it works as intended the first time around and then in the subsequent clicks it behaves oddly.

In the second click it places the tooltip in the lower right corner, then in the fourth click the tooltip somehow disappears. In the fifth click it gets back to its place and after that moves back and forth to the corner and to its place at each click.

The behavior I am looking for is that at each click, in any of the triggers, it should make the callback and show the tooltip at the desired place, hiding on mouseout. Only one tooltip shows at a time.

This is the script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tool").click(function(){
        var tool = $(this).attr("value");
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var tool_height = $("#tooltip_box").height();
        var tip_top = offset.top - tool_height + 20;
        var tip_left = offset.left +100;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tooltip.php",
        dataType:"html",
            data: "tool="+tool,
            success: function(data){
        $("#tooltip_box").html(data);
        $("#tooltip_box").offset({ top: tip_top, left: tip_left });
        //show tool tips 
                $('#tooltip_box').show();    
                $('.tool').mouseout(function () {
                    $("#tooltip_box").hide();
                });
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

These are examples of the triggers:

```
<span class="z2">Safety items(qty)
    <a href="#"><img id="tip1" src="img/i.png" class="tool" value="1000" title=""/></a>
</span>

<span class="z4">Performance
    <a href="#"><img id="tip2" src="img/i.png" class="tool" value="1001" title=""/></a>
</span>
```

The tooltip itself:

```
<div id="tooltip_box"></div>
```

Comment: How about "working" example on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: you have typo in HTML `href="#'` shoud be `href="#"` - apostrof/quotes

Comment: gevgeny, please find fiddle at [http://jsfiddle.net/RunLC/1/]. I have excluded Ajax call and adjusted it a bit to suit the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the use of offset() to position the tooltip. Apparently it feeds on itself.

I changed to css() and get this to work.

Please see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RunLC/15/.

The code below was adapted from my original code to suit jsfiddle.

```
$(".tool").click(function () {
var tool = $(this).attr("value");
var offset = $(this).offset();
var tool_height = $("#tooltip_box").height();
var tip_top = (offset.top - tool_height) + 200;
var tip_left = offset.left + 50;
$("#tooltip_box").html('tooltip text blalallal');
$("#tooltip_box").css("top",tip_top);
$("#tooltip_box").css("left",tip_left);

//show tool tips 
$('#tooltip_box').show();
$('.tool').mouseout(function () {
    $("#tooltip_box").hide();
});
});
```